# Where to hook into post content?

Tags: filters, hooks, content, the-content

Which hook or filter is used to edit the post content before `the_content` filter is applied to it.

For instance, if I wanted to add **Hello World,** as the first text in every post.

Comment: when the post is created, the action "save_post" is called with "update = FALSE" : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: that's _not quite_ what i'm looking for

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `the_content` with an high prioriety (lower number).

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
  return 'Hello World '.$content;
}, 0);
```

You can even use negative priority:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
  return 'Hello World '.$content;
}, -10);
```

Note that this will apply everytime `'the_content'` is used, no matter the post type, or if the target post is part of main query or not.

For more control you can use `loop_start` / `loop_end` actions to add and remove the filter:

```
// the function that edits post content
function my_edit_content( $content ) {
  global $post;
  // only edit specific post types
  $types = array( 'post', 'page' );
  if ( $post && in_array( $post->post_type, $types, true ) ) {
     $content = 'Hello World '. $content;
  }

  return $content;
}

// add the filter when main loop starts
add_action( 'loop_start', function( WP_Query $query ) {
   if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
     add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_edit_content', -10 );
   }
} );

// remove the filter when main loop ends
add_action( 'loop_end', function( WP_Query $query ) {
   if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'my_edit_content' ) ) {
     remove_filter( 'the_content', 'my_edit_content' );
   }
} );
```

Comment: in which file should you add this code?

Comment: @UriAbramson you can put it in your theme's functions.php or code your custom plugin

Answer (score 2):

There is no other global filter applied before `the_content` - you can use the [`$priority`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) argument in your `add_filter` call to ensure your function runs before any others:

```
function wpse_225625_to_the_top( $content ) {
    return "Hello World\n\n\$content";
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_225625_to_the_top', -1 /* Super important yo */  );
```